# Batching Invoices in SSRS - One Invoice per Customer

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a written an invoice report that bundles up various charges to customers during a month.  I have a filter set to a Parameter for a customer code that I am using for testing purposes.  The final product, however, I would like to be able to specify a date and have a separate invoice (ideally it's own PDF) generated for each customer.  Is this achievable in SSRS?

Notes:  Invoice number is a generated field that is a combo of MM-YYYY-CustCode so we don't need a register or some sort of incrementing facility for the invoice number.

Emailing the resulting PDFs to one email address is acceptable so we don't need the system to pull a unique address for each customer.

The selection string from the SQL is as follows (not sure its needed but just in case)

```
 CAST(VP_BSL_OWnerTrn.accountingdate AS DATE) = @accountingdate  
  AND (VP_BSL_OWnerTrn.code = 'Rental Com'
  OR VP_BSL_OWnerTrn.code = 'Mgmt Fee'
  OR VP_BSL_OWnerTrn.code = 'Gifts/Amen'
  OR VP_BSL_OWnerTrn.code = 'Handling')
  AND VP_BSL_OWnerTrn.Price_Local <> 0
  AND VP_BSL_OWnerTrn.RoomNo = @RoomNo
```

Thanks in advance for any help/advice.

Comment: does the result show you every invoice number for the same customer?

Comment: This does not have anything to do with the [tag:batch-file] tag!

Comment: Report design wise you'd have a list that groups on the things you want a page per. So if you want a page per customer, group on that. If you want a page per customer per day, group on those two things. If you want a page per invoice, group on that.. etc. etc.

Comment: So you would have to do as a multiple age report rather than a pdf per customer?  Sorry for the incorrect tag.